# Custom template for all woo commerce categories

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am new with Woo commerce and want to know that how i can create template that will work for all Woo commerce categories. I am able to find out answer that are working for specific to any category (taxonomy-product_cat-SLUG.php) but i want this for all categories.
I have already copied template folder of Woo commerce plugin in my theme but i am not able to locate category template.
I will appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to locate that file in my theme.
For categories woocommerce.php in root directory of my theme is working and i am able to complete my task.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were looking for archive.php. You have edit archive.php or use hooks to modify all category pages. Copy plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive.php to themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/archive.php. Not sure how woocommerce.php is working for your.